# how to reload fusion chart properties with dynamic data

Tags: angularjs, fusioncharts

I am using fusion chart to show graph but I am unable to load data with chart properties.
when I run my code, chart come first and after refresh I am getting that data.
so I am not getting how to reload data with chart

```
angular.module("inventory.states.material_movement", [])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, templateRoot) {
        $stateProvider.state('main.report_material_movement_display', {
            'url': '/material_movement/material_group_id/:materialGroupId/material_id/:materialId',
            'templateUrl': templateRoot + '/reports/material_movement/chart.html',
            'resolve': {
                bCurves: ['MaterialMovementService', '$stateParams', function (MaterialMovementService, $stateParams) {
                        return MaterialMovementService.query({
                            'materialGroupId': $stateParams.materialGroupId,
                            'materialId': $stateParams.materialId

                        });
                    }]
            },
            'controller': 'MaterialMovementDisplayController'
        });
    })
    .controller('MaterialMovementDisplayController', function (MaterialMovementService, $filter, $state, bCurves, $stateParams, $scope) {

        $scope.bCurves = [];
        $scope.bCurves = bCurves;

        $scope.balanceCurveData = {
            chart: {
                "caption": "Material Movement Curve",
                //              "subCaption": "Last week",
                "xAxisName": "Date",
                "yAxisName": "Quantity ",
                //              "numberPrefix": "$",
                "paletteColors": "#0075c2",
                "bgColor": "#ffffff",
                "showBorder": "0",
                "showCanvasBorder": "0",
                "plotBorderAlpha": "10",
                "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
                "plotFillAlpha": "50",
                "showXAxisLine": "1",
                "axisLineAlpha": "25",
                "divLineAlpha": "10",
                "showValues": "1",
                "showAlternateHGridColor": "0",
                "captionFontSize": "14",
                "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
                "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
                "toolTipColor": "#ffffff",
                "toolTipBorderThickness": "0",
                "toolTipBgColor": "#000000",
                "toolTipBgAlpha": "80",
                "toolTipBorderRadius": "2",
                "toolTipPadding": "5"
            },
            data: [{
                    'label': " ",
                    "value": " "
                }]
        };
        angular.forEach($scope.bCurves, function (value) {
            var x_label = $filter('date')(value.transactionDate, "MMM d, y");
            $scope.balanceCurveData.data.push({
                'label': x_label,
                'value': value.balance
            });
        });
    });
```

Here I am not able to pass data generated by for.Each() loop with chart object.
code is working but only unable to pass data with fusion charts

```
<div id="graph_container">
<fusioncharts
width="600"
height="400"
type="line"
datasource="{{balanceCurveData}}">
```

Comment: hey, need few information to understand your problem. Here I believe you are using angular-ui/ui-router. 
In your statement you said your chart come first then the data on refresh. What does that mean? Is it the case that stateProvider does not retrieve the data in first time and chart gets rendered without any data? Can you elaborate the statement.

Comment: hie, Yes actually chart gets rendered without any data, and when I click on refresh button that time data renders on  chart. other things are working properly and correct data is also coming but it comes on refresh.even when chart loads first time without any data that time i am getting data in console but not rendered on chart. that stateProvider data runs only on refresh.

Comment: Try updating the data inside `$scope.$apply` function. 
And the refresh button you were talking about, is it a separate button in DOM or are you talking about browser refresh button?

Comment: I am talking about browser refresh button.and can you please tell me how to use $scope.apply here

Comment: `$scope.$apply(function(){$scope.balanceCurveData.data.push({
                'label': x_label,
                'value': value.balance
            });})`

Comment: I tried this one, but I am getting an ERROR i.e     <pre>Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Answer (score 0):

when your chart loads what happens to the div? Is the datasource filled with the chart attributes? And after you refresh what happens to the datasource again? Moreover, if you can provide a fiddle link, this problem can be investigated thoroughly.

Comment: datasource filled the chart attribute but but not on single click. i need to refresh the page to fill that data